# ANativeWindow_Lock only runs three times and then hangs

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk

I'm trying to draw using ANativeWindow in Android.

My Java code looks like this: It creates a Surface View, adds it to the SurfaceHolder callback, and uses the implemented methods to call c code.

```
public class FrameworkActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setContentView(surfaceView);
}
@Override protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    cOnPause();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    cReleaseSurface();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    cSetSurface(holder.getSurface());
}

}
```

Which calls c code that looks like this (though it's a bit abbreviated): cSetSurface gets an ANativeWindow, it passes it to setSurface, which formats it and then starts a drawing thread that loops until onPause() is called. The drawing function locks and unlocks the window. "printLog" just writes to the log.

```
void cOnStart(){
    running=1;
}
void cOnPause(){
    running=0;
    pthread_join(drawing,NULL);
    printLog("Pausing...");
}
void cSetSurface(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject surface){
      ANativeWindow *thisWindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env,surface);
      setSurface(thisWindow);
}

void setSurface(ANativeWindow* window){
    pthread_join(drawing,NULL);
    thisWindow=window;
    screenHeight=ANativeWindow_getHeight(thisWindow);
    screenWidth=ANativeWindow_getWidth(thisWindow);
    //3 is RGB888, 8 bits per color
    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(thisWindow,screenWidth,screenHeight,3);
    pthread_attr_t attr2;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
    pthread_create(&drawing, &attr2, &onDrawFrame,NULL);
}

void cReleaseSurface(){
    printLog("Releasing the window");
    pthread_join(drawing,NULL);
    ANativeWindow_release(thisWindow);
}
void onDrawFrame(){
    while(running!=0){
        printLog("Got the window");
        if (running!=0 && ANativeWindow_lock(thisWindow,&buffer,NULL)==0){
            printLog("Drawing");
            ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(thisWindow);
            printLog("Unlocking and posting");
       }
   }
}
```

When I run this, it loops fine exactly three times; on the fourth loop, it "hangs"; it becomes completely unresponsive and stops logging anything. It always hangs after printing "Got the window" and never makes it to printing "Drawing". If I comment out the "ANativeWindow_lock" line, then it doesn't hang (it just gives errors about unlocking an unlocked window). So I'm pretty sure the problem is that ANativeWindow_lock is causing the problem. I would also guess that it happens because some other part of the program is deallocating or otherwise changing the native window while ANativeWindow_lock is still trying to access it; that's why I had both setSurface and cReleaseSurface wait until the drawing thread is done. But the problem still happens.

Does anyone know why it's having problems, or any resources I could use to delve deeper into what ANativeWindow_lock is doing, so I can see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Might be worth logging the value of `thisWindow` to ensure it isn't changing out from under you.